# How to connect ASP.NET Application to Remote SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005, database-connection, connection-string

I would like to know what is the correct connection string to use in order to connect to a remote SQL Server 2005.

My webserver is IIS 7.5
.Net Framwork 4.0
and A remote SQL Server 2005.

Comment: https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2005/

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass IP address of server in the Server, database name, and credentials mainly username and password, here is sample to do like this:

```
Server=ServerIp;Database=DatabaseName;User Id=Username;
Password=Password;
```

See more details [**HERE**](https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2005/)